# Unable to grant permission on table

Tags: postgresql

I've been given credentials to a postgres database that I'm told it has privileges to create new users and grant them access to tables. This is half true.

I wish to create a new user:

```
create user foo login encrypted password 'bar';
commit;
```

This is OK. Now I'm trying to that user grant some specific access to selected tables:

```
grant select, insert, update on table baz to foo;
```

The response is `[42501] ERROR: permission denied for relation baz`.

It seems that this user I've been given can't event select from the tables I wish to grant access to. `select * from baz` also gives a 42501 error.

The query `select distinct(grantor) from information_schema.role_table_grants;` returns one username (let's call it 'bob'). Should I be speaking with Bob about getting the privs I need?

Comment: What do you mean with root user? By default there is no user named "root" in Postgres. Did you create that account yourself? If yes how and with which privileges?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name has a good point... Do you mean that you have been given root access to the [unix] server that runs the database, rather than the database software itself? You so that you are told that they are root, but is your username `root`? Or are you using `postgres`? Please clarify.

Comment: @Greenonline: no, you don't need root access to the database server. You don't even need shell access to the database server - you only need to be able to connect to the Postgres server using a SQL tool (e.g. `psql`)

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. I've edited the question in light of what you've taught me.

Comment: @greenonline I'm not on the server. I logged into the DB with a user that just happened to be called 'root'.

Comment: Then I'll repeat my question: "*Did you create that account yourself? If yes how and with which privileges?*" - just because a user is _called_ root, doesn't mean he has any special privileges

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's answered in the first sentence.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I appreciate that root access is not required, I'm not quite sure how you inferred that I thought it was, from my comment. I was merely backing you up and trying to clarify if the OP was actually logging on to a console, as the `root` username implied (because as you rightly say "By default there is no user named `root` in Postgres"), or via `psql` using a strange username (i.e. `root`). We can now see that the OP is connecting using some credentials, unfortunately named `root`, that they did not create themselves, with user creation and access granting permissions. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a guess, your user isn't the owner of the tables and hasn't been granted rights to them `WITH GRANT OPTION` so it can delegate them.

The database administrator must do something like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser WITH GRANT OPTION
```

and should probably also `GRANT` similar rights on `SEQUENCE`s, on the schema its self, etc.

The `WITH GRANT OPTION` gives the user `myuser` the right to in turn `GRANT` the assigned rights to others.

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) for details.

You might also be interested in `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`.